# Modify multiple keys of dictionary by a mapping dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dict, one original and one for mapping the original one's key to another value simultaneously,for instance:

**original dict**:

```
built_dict={'China':{'deportivo-cuenca-u20':{'danny':'test1'}},
            'Germany':{'ajax-amsterdam-youth':{'lance':'test2'}}}
```

**mapping dict**:

```
club_team_dict={'deportivo-cuenca-u20':'deportivo','ajax-amsterdam-youth':'ajax'}
```

It works well if I use the following code to change the key of the nested dict of original dict,like

```
def club2team(built_dict,club_team_dict):
for row in built_dict:
    # print test_dict[row]
    for sub_row in built_dict[row]:
        for key in club_team_dict:
            # the key of club_team_dict must be a subset of test_dict,or you have to check it and then replace it
            if sub_row==key:
                built_dict[row][club_team_dict[sub_row]] = built_dict[row].pop(sub_row)
return built_dict
```

and the **result**:

```
{'Germany': {'ajax': {'lance': 'test2'}}, 'China': {'deportivo': {'danny': 'test1'}}}
```

so far so good, however if I have a dict with multiple key mapping to the same key,for example,my original dict is like

```
built_dict={'China':{'deportivo-cuenca-u20':{'danny':'test1'}},
            'Germany':{'ajax-amsterdam-youth':{'lance':'test2'},
                       'ajax-amsterdam':{'tony':'test3'}}}
```

and the mapping dict with more then 1 key mapping to the same value,like:

```
club_team_dict={'deportivo-cuenca-u20':'deportivo',
                'ajax-amsterdam-youth':'ajax',
                'ajax-amsterdam':'ajax'}
```

as you can see, both `'ajax-amsterdam-youth'`and `'ajax-amsterdam-youth'` are mapping to `'ajax'`,and the trouble is when I use the same code to execute it, the original dict's size has been changed during the iteration

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I want to get a result with nested list for the same key like this

```
{'Germany': {'ajax':[{'lance': 'test2'},
                     {'tony' : 'test3'}]}},
 'China': {'deportivo': [{'danny': 'test1'}]}}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found a solution for this,the code:

```
def club2team(built_dict,club_team_dict):
for row in built_dict:
    # print test_dict[row]
    for sub_row in built_dict[row].keys():
        for key in club_team_dict:
            # the key of club_team_dict must be a subset of test_dict,or you have to check it and then replace it
            if sub_row==key:
                # built_dict[row][club_team_dict[sub_row]] = built_dict[row].pop(sub_row)
                built_dict[row].setdefault(club_team_dict[sub_row],[]).append(built_dict[row].pop(sub_row))
return built_dict
```

pay attention to the `for sub_row in built_dict[row].keys():` and `setdefault()` method, I used to believe that in `python 2.7`, the default iteration for dict is just iterate the keys(), however, this time it proves it's a little different, maybe you have better solution, please show me and it will be appreciate,thank you

Comment: Just a heads up, this won't work in Python 3 (where `.keys()` returns a live view of the `dict` that will complain about mid-iteration modification too). If you want to make it compatible with both Py2 and Py3, change the loop to `for sub_row in tuple(built_dict[row]):` which will guarantee a shallow copy no matter what version of Python you're on.

Comment: Yes,thank you, both list or tuple can be used to make a copy and work in both python 2.x and 3.x